# infinite scroll - apply jquery effects to elements on all scrolled pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I'm using the [infinite-ajax-scroll plugin](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll) along with a [countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and a [hover Caption plugin](http://ryun.github.io/HCaptions/) and Metro JS (http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs).

The JQuery effects work well on the first page, however they aren't applied to the pages loaded via the infinite scroll plugin.

I know I need to use the `onLoadItems` or `onRenderComplete` inside the Infinite Scroll initialization, however, I am not that great with JQuery syntax and would appreciate any help in getting this working.

```
//code for countdown applied to every element
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#countdown_$id').countdown({until: new Date($year, $month - 1, $day, $hour, $minute, $secs)});
    });
</script>";
echo '<div class="defaultCountdown" id="countdown_'.$id.'"></div>';

//code that applied hover captions and infinite scroll
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hcaption').hcaptions({
        effect: "fade"
    });
    //animate tiles
    $(".live-tile").liveTile({pauseOnHover: true});

    // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
    jQuery.ias({
        container: '#main', // main container where data goes to append
        item: '.element', // single items
        pagination: '.paginate', // page navigation
        next: '.paginate a', // next page selector
        loader: '<img src="public/img/ajax-loader.gif"/>', // loading gif
        loaderDelay: 200,
        thresholdMargin: -600,
        noneleft: 'No more discounts', //Contains the message to be displayed when there are no more pages left to load
        triggerPageThreshold: '10', // show "load more" if scroll more than this to stop
        trigger: "",
        onLoadItems: function (newElements) {
            // hide new items while they are loading
            var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
                opacity: 0
            });
            // ensure that images load before adding to isotope layout
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
                // show elems now they're ready
                $newElems.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
                $container.isotope('insert', $newElems, true);
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
    //end infinite
});
```

Comment: Which effect isn't working? Is it the captions plugin? Could you post a demo in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: None of the plugins I am using work including the hcaptions,countdown and live-tile

Comment: Real quick...are you adding them into your html properly?
script tags at the top or bottom of your page?
There could be a number of factors causing this issue.  We'd need a little more info.  Possibly an example.

Comment: I've update my answer and the demo, maybe you can give a try, it seems to work correctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `onLoadItems` **and** the `onRenderComplete` when you initialize the scroll like :

```
jQuery.ias({
    container: '#main', // main container where data goes to append
    item: '.element', // single items
    pagination: '.paginate', // page navigation
    next: '.paginate a', // next page selector
    loader: '<img src="public/img/ajax-loader.gif"/>', // loading gif
    loaderDelay: 200,
    thresholdMargin: -600,
    noneleft: 'No more discounts'
    triggerPageThreshold: '10',
    trigger: "",
    onLoadItems: function (newElements) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
            opacity: 0
        });
        // ensure that images load before adding to isotope layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
            // show elems now they're ready
            $newElems.animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            $container.isotope('insert', $newElems, true);
        });
        setTimeout("$('.hcaption').hcaptions({effect: 'fade'})",1000);
        setTimeout('$(".live-tile, .flip-list").not(".exclude").liveTile()',1000);
        return true;
    }
});
//end infinite
```

[DEMO](http://balthazargronon.com/stack/leetee/page1.html)

I've try also with

```
onRenderComplete: function(items) {
    $('.hcaption').hcaptions({effect: "fade"});
    $(".live-tile, .flip-list").not(".exclude").liveTile();
}
```

And it work fine.

Comment: doesn't work for me, in fact when I add the Onrendercomplete function it stops the infinate scroll from loading new items.

Comment: thanks but, that doesn't seem to work either.  Its strange as its not throwing any errors.

Comment: And with `$('.hcaption').hcaptions({effect: "fade"});` ? Also try to set a little timeout to let time to the items to render

Comment: Like edit, you can also call another function where you reload the `hcaptions`, but don't know what happend if captions are loaded twice

Comment: Can you provide an example?  Im struggling to understand.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your effort, I will give this a try now :)

Comment: yes thats great, both the hcaptions and live-tiles work.  I just need to try and sort out the countdown, but thats done differently.